# Passing simple_form_for object from one partial to another partial through a javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a partial with a form. It also has an empty div. I need to append another partial into this div using ajax when a button on first partial is clicked. The second partial has some form elements to be added to same form object used in first form. I tried it passing it through the javascript but it didn't work.

Following is my first partial (HAML),

```
= link_to "Emp", {:action => 'edit', :id => @emp.id, :object => @emp, :f => f}, :remote => true

.div1
```

My javascript is

```
$(function(){$('.div1').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'partial2', :locals => {:id => @emp.id, :f => f, :object => f.object})%>");});
```